# Unknown provider error when injecting AngularJS factory into controller

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to inject my factory into my controller and I'm getting this error from AngularJS:

> Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider

I have looked through almost all of the questions on here and still cannot find a solution to my problem. I believe my controller and factory and declared correctly and the injection is correct but it looks like this isn't the case.

My factory code is as follows:

```
var app = angular.module('test', []);

 app.factory('processingFactory', function () {
  var factory = {};

  factory.newTest = function() {
   console.log("TEST");
  }

 return factory;

});
```

This is then injected into the controller which looks like this:

```
angular.module("test", ["angularModalService", "anguFixedHeaderTable", 
'angular-loading-bar', "ngResource", "agGrid", 
'ui.tree']).controller("dashboardController", [
"$scope",
"$timeout",
"$http",
"$window",
"$interval",
"$resource",
"ModalService",
"$filter",
'$q',
'processingFactory',
 function($scope, $timeout, $http, $window, $interval, $resource, 
 ModalService, $filter, $q, processingFactory) {
   //other code removed
   $scope.newWorkorder = processingFactory.newWorkorder;
  }
 ]);
```

This function is called through a button click on the web page. All of the files needed are in script tags on this html page. I am fairly new to angular so this could be a simple error or something I am not aware of.

Comment: `angular.module` injections are for modules (i.e. dependancies). You don't need to inject the factory, since it's already attached to the right module - `"test"`. But you do need to change `angular.module('test', [])` to `angular.module('test')`

Answer (score 0):

Calling `angular.module` with an array as the second argument declares a module, which can only happen for any given module name. You are declaring the module twice (once in your controller code, and again in your factory code).

Try changing the first part of your factory code to:

```
var app = angular.module('test');
```

If you are doing the same thing elsewhere in the app you will need to remove the second argument there too, so that there is only one module declaration in the whole app.

Answer (score 0):

if there are any dependencies for your module "test" why do not you have them declared in the first line itself like:

```
var app = angular.module("test", ["angularModalService", "anguFixedHeaderTable", 
'angular-loading-bar', "ngResource", "agGrid", 
'ui.tree']);
```

Then declare your controller like::

```
app.controler(...)
```

Things should work fine.